# How to list all types (running, zombie, etc.) of processes currently in linux with native python library

Tags: python, linux, process

I want to list all processes' information currently exist in Linux system. I find that someone uses `psutil` library to accomplish this task. However, my development environment can only support native Python library. It means that I can't use any external modules.

It there exist a simple way to accomplish this mission?

Thanks.

Comment: If by 'native library' you mean you can only use the standard Python library, then you should know that the standard library does not provide the means to access process information. However, Linux (and other UNIX systems) provides the `/proc` filesystem which you can access using standard filesystem operations (`os.listdir`, `open`, `read`, etc...) and which contains the information you are looking for. However, you will need to implement all the processing logic yourself. Take a look at the `proc` manpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you are trying to accomplish but linux commands can be run using the  [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("pstree",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()[0]

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ps" ,"aux"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works but a litter more complicate.